how to ensure MVVM View has binding to a specific method
I am quite new to MVVM and I was wondering if it is possible to ensure that a view contains somwhere a binding to a specific method. For instance, using MVC I would have an Iview interface with all the methods I need which are then implemented by every concrete view class.
In other words, I would like to have something that guarantee a behaviour (as an interace does) and a way to apply this thing to a view so that it must contain a binding to each of those methods that I somehow declared.
I know that I could follow the interface approach of MVC editing the code-behind of the view, but it would not be compliant with the MVVM concept: correct me if I am wrong, but I understood that view should only use bindings in the XAML file to viewModel methods and not declare its own methods in the code-behind.
Thanks in advance

You could try with a converter?

I am sorry for being a noob, but can you explain what you mean by "converter" or link something with that explenation?

You could find the doc here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters?view=net-maui-8.0 i'm not an expert but i think this links could help you.

As far as I understood, Converters do a different job: they convert data type when it is sent from view model to the view or viceversa.
This is an interesting thing that I honestly didn't know, but what I need is a way to ensure that the view calls some methods, I don't need a conversion from the type shown in the the view and the one stored in the view model.
Anyway, thanks a lot for your efforts

And Can call thé method on the getter. For exemple : MyAttribute { cet { return MyMethod();}}. You can bind MyAttribute

I missed that. Tomorrow I'll be back to you. Thanks

I am experiencing some problems, so  I will not be able to try what you suggested today. I'll be back as soon as possible, sorry

It s working for you ?

I am deeply sorry for the time that took me to answer you.
Given that, I guess you solution is surely a work around that can be used, but is not a "formal" solution like interface usage would be
